# Java - How to convert InputStream into an appropriate format to use IBM Watson's Speech-to-Text service?

Tags: java, websocket, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, vonage

I am trying to achieve live transcription of a phone conversation by utilizing both Nexmo and IBM Watson services. I have setup a websocket to receive `InputStream` of binary audio from Nexmo. I have also setup a websocket connection to IBM Watson's speech-to-text service. The audio stream I receive from Nexmo is of `PCM` encoding at a frequency of either 8 kHz or 16 kHz. The frame size of each message obtained from Nexmo is of 20 ms long.

IBM Watson Java SDK's Websocket interface expects a `InputStream` with the correct encoding information for a successful transcription. The following are the data conditioning I have tried:

- Delegate the raw `InputStream` obtained from Nexmo to Watson with
  content-type as `"audio/l16; rate=16000; endianness=little-endian"`
- Obtain a `AudioInputStream` object by using the `static` method `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(InputStream inputStream)`. This method supposedly inferences the format of the input stream and returns `AudioStream` object.
- Obtain `AudioStream` object by using the static method `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioFormat targetFormat,                                                    AudioInputStream sourceStream)` by passing the following `AudioFormat` argument

  - `audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16, 1, AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED, 16, 16000, true);`

But in all the above tries, I failed to obtain any sort of transcription from IBM services. I do get response from IBM that the websocket has been connected and is in `listening state` when I first connect to the service. There are no logs available in IBM cloud to see what's going on. I have read through SO and IBM developer forums, but could not find any suitable examples. I am quite convinced that the way I condition the data I obtain from Nexmo is not ideal for Watson services. How can I condition my data appropriately in order to transcribe speech with IBM Watson?

This my very simplified (to improve readability) code sample (different methods of various functionality added together)

```
// method to return Nexmo's NCCO, when the call is answered
public static String connectToWebSocket()
{
    JsonArray ncco = new JsonArray();

    JsonObject enclosingObject = new JsonObject();
    enclosingObject.addProperty("action", "connect");

    JsonObject webSocketEndpoint = new JsonObject();
    webSocketEndpoint.addProperty("type", "websocket");
    webSocketEndpoint.addProperty("uri", "ws://websocket-uri/call-stream");
    webSocketEndpoint.addProperty("content-type", "audio/l16;rate=16000");

    JsonObject header = new JsonObject();
    header.addProperty("app", "demo");

    webSocketEndpoint.add("header", header);

    JsonArray endpointArray = new JsonArray();
    endpointArray.add(webSocketEndpoint);

    enclosingObject.add("endpoint", endpointArray);

    ncco.add(enclosingObject);
    return ncco.toString();
}

// WebSocketController' onMessage method (receiving Nexmo's binary audio) 
@OnMessage
public void onMessage(InputStream inputStream, Session session)
{
    //transcriptionService.recognizeVoice(inputStream);
}

// IBMTransriptionService's recognizeVoice method
public void recognizeVoice(InputStream stream)
{
    if(stream == null) return;

    try
    {
        audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 16, 1, AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED, 16, 16000, true);
        RecognizeOptions recognizeOptions = new RecognizeOptions.Builder().audio(new AudioInputStream(stream, audioFormat, 16))
            .contentType("audio/l16; rate=16000; endianness=little-endian")
            .interimResults(true)
            .build();

        this.speechToText.setEndPoint("https://gateway-syd.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");
        this.speechToText.recognizeUsingWebSocket(recognizeOptions, this.transcriptionReceiver);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.error("Failed when creating audio stream" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Additional links:

- This is Nexmo documentation detailing the formats of the binary audio
  transmitted via [websocket](https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/websockets)

  Watson Speech-to-Text API [reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/java.html?java#websocket_methods)

Answer (score 0):

What model are you using for the request to Watson? the Nexmo speech is from a phonecall so even if you are using 16Khz you want to set it to a Narrowband model, eg `en-US_NarrowbandModel`

Comment: Yes I am using `en-US_NarrowbandModel`. Is there anything else I should be looking at?